# How to get nested vectors to top level

Tags: clojure

After some manipulation, I get this data structure:

```
(((((([3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9211]
      [3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9296]
      [3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9216])
     ([3844 4465 6555 5551 5151 5192] [3844 4465 6555 5551 5151 5184])
     ([3844 4465 6555 5551 5184 8464]))
    (([3844 4465 6555 5565 6561 6112] [3844 4465 6555 5565 6561 6175])
     ([3844 4465 6555 5565 6533 3367]
      [3844 4465 6555 5565 6533 3321]
      [3844 4465 6555 5565 6533 3364])))
   ((([3844 4465 6561 6112 1281 8177] [3844 4465 6561 6112 1281 8128])
     ([3844 4465 6561 6112 1296 9633])
     ([3844 4465 6561 6112 1225 2556] [3844 4465 6561 6112 1225 2512])
     ([3844 4465 6561 6112 1247 4774]
      [3844 4465 6561 6112 1247 4720]
      [3844 4465 6561 6112 1247 4761]
      [3844 4465 6561 6112 1247 4753])
     ([3844 4465 6561 6112 1275 7526] [3844 4465 6561 6112 1275 7569])
     ([3844 4465 6561 6112 1288 8855] [3844 4465 6561 6112 1288 8836]))
    (([3844 4465 6561 6175 7526 2625]
      [3844 4465 6561 6175 7526 2640]
      [3844 4465 6561 6175 7526 2673]
      [3844 4465 6561 6175 7526 2628])
     ([3844 4465 6561 6175 7569 6943])))
   ((([3844 4465 6533 3367 6786 8646]
      [3844 4465 6533 3367 6786 8614]
      [3844 4465 6533 3367 6786 8640]
      [3844 4465 6533 3367 6786 8626]
      [3844 4465 6533 3367 6786 8649])
     ([3844 4465 6533 3367 6724 2485]
      [3844 4465 6533 3367 6724 2465]
      [3844 4465 6533 3367 6724 2415]))
    (([3844 4465 6533 3321 2133 3367] [3844 4465 6533 3321 2133 3364])
     ([3844 4465 6533 3321 2145 4558]
      [3844 4465 6533 3321 2145 4510]
      [3844 4465 6533 3321 2145 4560])
     ([3844 4465 6533 3321 2147 4774]
      [3844 4465 6533 3321 2147 4720]
      [3844 4465 6533 3321 2147 4761]
      [3844 4465 6533 3321 2147 4753])
     ([3844 4465 6533 3321 2116 1653]
      [3844 4465 6533 3321 2116 1617]
      [3844 4465 6533 3321 2116 1651]
      [3844 4465 6533 3321 2116 1680]
      [3844 4465 6533 3321 2116 1681]))
    (([3844 4465 6533 3364 6441 4186]
      [3844 4465 6533 3364 6441 4187]
      [3844 4465 6533 3364 6441 4141])
     ([3844 4465 6533 3364 6426 2625]
      [3844 4465 6533 3364 6426 2640]
      [3844 4465 6533 3364 6426 2673]
      [3844 4465 6533 3364 6426 2628]))))
  (((([3844 4485 8515 1520 2059 5985]
      [3844 4485 8515 1520 2059 5922]
      [3844 4485 8515 1520 2059 5929]
      [3844 4485 8515 1520 2059 5995])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1520 2035 3553]
      [3844 4485 8515 1520 2035 3570]
      [3844 4485 8515 1520 2035 3577])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1520 2025 2556] [3844 4485 8515 1520 2025 2512])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1520 2080 8037])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1520 2016 1653]
      [3844 4485 8515 1520 2016 1617]
      [3844 4485 8515 1520 2016 1651]
      [3844 4485 8515 1520 2016 1680]
      [3844 4485 8515 1520 2016 1681]))
    (([3844 4485 8515 1596 9633 3367]
      [3844 4485 8515 1596 9633 3321]
      [3844 4485 8515 1596 9633 3364]))
    (([3844 4485 8515 1541 4186 8646]
      [3844 4485 8515 1541 4186 8614]
      [3844 4485 8515 1541 4186 8640]
      [3844 4485 8515 1541 4186 8626]
      [3844 4485 8515 1541 4186 8649])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1541 4187 8778])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1541 4141 4186] [3844 4485 8515 1541 4141 4187]))
    (([3844 4485 8515 1521 2133 3367]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2133 3321]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2133 3364])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1521 2145 4558]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2145 4510]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2145 4560])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1521 2147 4774]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2147 4720]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2147 4761]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2147 4753])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1521 2116 1653]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2116 1617]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2116 1651]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2116 1680]
      [3844 4485 8515 1521 2116 1681]))
    (([3844 4485 8515 1540 4096 9633])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1540 4030 3081]
      [3844 4485 8515 1540 4030 3015]
      [3844 4485 8515 1540 4030 3010]
      [3844 4485 8515 1540 4030 3025])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1540 4033 3367]
      [3844 4485 8515 1540 4033 3321]
      [3844 4485 8515 1540 4033 3364])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1540 4095 9560]
      [3844 4485 8515 1540 4095 9591]
      [3844 4485 8515 1540 4095 9517]))
    (([3844 4485 8515 1525 2556 5671]
      [3844 4485 8515 1525 2556 5688]
      [3844 4485 8515 1525 2556 5625])
     ([3844 4485 8515 1525 2512 1281]
      [3844 4485 8515 1525 2512 1296]
      [3844 4485 8515 1525 2512 1225]
      [3844 4485 8515 1525 2512 1247]
      [3844 4485 8515 1525 2512 1275]
      [3844 4485 8515 1525 2512 1288]))))
  (((([3844 4489 8910 1071 7140 4096]
      [3844 4489 8910 1071 7140 4030]
      [3844 4489 8910 1071 7140 4033]
      [3844 4489 8910 1071 7140 4095]))
    (([3844 4489 8910 1081 8177 7740]
      [3844 4489 8910 1081 8177 7750]
      [3844 4489 8910 1081 8177 7744]
      [3844 4489 8910 1081 8177 7756])
     ([3844 4489 8910 1081 8128 2882]
      [3844 4489 8910 1081 8128 2850]
      [3844 4489 8910 1081 8128 2821]
      [3844 4489 8910 1081 8128 2839]))
    (([3844 4489 8910 1080 8037 3725]
      [3844 4489 8910 1080 8037 3721]
      [3844 4489 8910 1080 8037 3744]
      [3844 4489 8910 1080 8037 3741]))
    (([3844 4489 8910 1024 2485 8515])
     ([3844 4489 8910 1024 2465 6555]
      [3844 4489 8910 1024 2465 6561]
      [3844 4489 8910 1024 2465 6533])
     ([3844 4489 8910 1024 2415 1520]
      [3844 4489 8910 1024 2415 1596]
      [3844 4489 8910 1024 2415 1541]
      [3844 4489 8910 1024 2415 1521]
      [3844 4489 8910 1024 2415 1540]
      [3844 4489 8910 1024 2415 1525]))
    (([3844 4489 8910 1089 8911 1128]
      [3844 4489 8910 1089 8911 1156]
      [3844 4489 8910 1089 8911 1176]
      [3844 4489 8910 1089 8911 1177]
      [3844 4489 8910 1089 8911 1162]
      [3844 4489 8910 1089 8911 1160])
     ([3844 4489 8910 1089 8965 6555]
      [3844 4489 8910 1089 8965 6561]
      [3844 4489 8910 1089 8965 6533]))
    (([3844 4489 8910 1045 4558 5886])
     ([3844 4489 8910 1045 4510 1071]
      [3844 4489 8910 1045 4510 1081]
      [3844 4489 8910 1045 4510 1080]
      [3844 4489 8910 1045 4510 1024]
      [3844 4489 8910 1045 4510 1089]
      [3844 4489 8910 1045 4510 1035])
     ([3844 4489 8910 1045 4560 6084]))
    (([3844 4489 8910 1035 3553 5356]
      [3844 4489 8910 1035 3553 5329]
      [3844 4489 8910 1035 3553 5370])
     ([3844 4489 8910 1035 3570 7056] [3844 4489 8910 1035 3570 7021])
     ([3844 4489 8910 1035 3577 7740]
      [3844 4489 8910 1035 3577 7750]
      [3844 4489 8910 1035 3577 7744]
      [3844 4489 8910 1035 3577 7756])))
   ((([3844 4489 8911 1128 2882 8281] [3844 4489 8911 1128 2882 8256])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1128 2850 5017]
      [3844 4489 8911 1128 2850 5041]
      [3844 4489 8911 1128 2850 5050])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1128 2821 2133]
      [3844 4489 8911 1128 2821 2145]
      [3844 4489 8911 1128 2821 2147]
      [3844 4489 8911 1128 2821 2116])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1128 2839 3916]
      [3844 4489 8911 1128 2839 3969]
      [3844 4489 8911 1128 2839 3940]))
    (([3844 4489 8911 1156 5671 7140])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1156 5688 8855] [3844 4489 8911 1156 5688 8836])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1156 5625 2556] [3844 4489 8911 1156 5625 2512]))
    (([3844 4489 8911 1176 7626 2625]
      [3844 4489 8911 1176 7626 2640]
      [3844 4489 8911 1176 7626 2673]
      [3844 4489 8911 1176 7626 2628]))
    (([3844 4489 8911 1177 7740 4096]
      [3844 4489 8911 1177 7740 4030]
      [3844 4489 8911 1177 7740 4033]
      [3844 4489 8911 1177 7740 4095])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1177 7750 5017]
      [3844 4489 8911 1177 7750 5041]
      [3844 4489 8911 1177 7750 5050])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1177 7744 4465] [3844 4489 8911 1177 7744 4485])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1177 7756 5671]
      [3844 4489 8911 1177 7756 5688]
      [3844 4489 8911 1177 7756 5625]))
    (([3844 4489 8911 1162 6241 4186]
      [3844 4489 8911 1162 6241 4187]
      [3844 4489 8911 1162 6241 4141])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1162 6256 5671]
      [3844 4489 8911 1162 6256 5688]
      [3844 4489 8911 1162 6256 5625])
     ([3844 4489 8911 1162 6216 1653]
      [3844 4489 8911 1162 6216 1617]
      [3844 4489 8911 1162 6216 1651]
      [3844 4489 8911 1162 6216 1680]
      [3844 4489 8911 1162 6216 1681]))
    (([3844 4489 8911 1160 6084 8464])))
   ((([3844 4489 8965 6555 5551 5192]
      [3844 4489 8965 6555 5551 5151]
      [3844 4489 8965 6555 5551 5184])
     ([3844 4489 8965 6555 5565 6561] [3844 4489 8965 6555 5565 6533]))
    (([3844 4489 8965 6561 6112 1281]
      [3844 4489 8965 6561 6112 1296]
      [3844 4489 8965 6561 6112 1225]
      [3844 4489 8965 6561 6112 1247]
      [3844 4489 8965 6561 6112 1275]
      [3844 4489 8965 6561 6112 1288])
     ([3844 4489 8965 6561 6175 7526] [3844 4489 8965 6561 6175 7569]))
    (([3844 4489 8965 6533 3367 6786] [3844 4489 8965 6533 3367 6724])
     ([3844 4489 8965 6533 3321 2133]
      [3844 4489 8965 6533 3321 2145]
      [3844 4489 8965 6533 3321 2147]
      [3844 4489 8965 6533 3321 2116])
     ([3844 4489 8965 6533 3364 6441]
      [3844 4489 8965 6533 3364 6426]))))))
```

As you can see, vectors are embedded at different levels. I want to get the total collection of vectors (single level) like so:

```
([3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9211]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9296]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9216]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5151 5192]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5151 5184]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5184 8464]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6561 6112]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6561 6175]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6533 3367]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6533 3321]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6533 3364]
 [3844 4465 6561 6112 1281 8177]
 [3844 4465 6561 6112 1281 8128]
 [3844 4465 6561 6112 1296 9633]
 [3844 4465 6561 6112 1225 2556]
 [3844 4465 6561 6112 1225 2512]
 [3844 4465 6561 6112 1247 4774]
 :...and-so-on...)
```

I don't want the nested seqs.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `(map flatten [....])`

Comment: the easiest would be something like that: `(filter vector? (tree-seq (complement vector?) seq data))`

Comment: Shape the data correctly in the first place.  Things like `mapcat` or `for` help with that.

Comment: @nakiya when writing questions, you can select a code block and hit ctrl-k to get it formatted as code properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's two of many approaches. If you are going to do a lot of stuff like this in your project (or want to work on making the data come out in a shape that's easier to work with), it may be worth adding a dependency on [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter):

```
user> (require '[com.rpl.specter :refer [select walker]])
nil
user> (select (walker vector?) data)
[[3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9211]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9296]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9216]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5151 5192]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5151 5184]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5184 8464]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6561 6112]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6561 6175]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6533 3367]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6533 3321]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6533 3364]
 [3844 4465 6561 6112 1281 8177] ...]
```

or if this is kind of a one-off then just hit it with tree-seq and filter the results as leetwinski suggests:

```
user> (filter vector? 
        (tree-seq (complement vector?) seq data))

([3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9211]
 [3844 4465 6555 5551 5192 9296]
 [3844 4465 6555 5565 6561 6175] ...)
```

Comment: I'm doing the project Euler questions. So, yes I do a lot of manipulation of data. Will try out Specter.